# Grunt.js Unable to read file (Error code: EISDIR)

Tags: javascript, import, gruntjs

My folder structure is as follows

- static/

  - js/

    - default/

      - main.js
    - lib/

      - someplugin.js
      - vendor/

        - jquery.js
        - tinyMce.js

Inside main.js I have the following code

```
@import '../lib/vendor/jquery.js';
@import '../lib/vendor/tinyMce.js';
@import '../lib/someplugin.js';
// ... more code ...
```

Every time I run `grunt` I'm getting the follwing error:

```
Warning: Unable to read "/PATH_TO_MY_APP/static/js/lib/vendor" file (Error code: EISDIR).
```

If I remove the tinyMce.js import line, grunt runs fine. So the problem must be with tinyMce, right? Wrong, if I cut all the content of tinyMce.js and paste it inside jquery.js (after jquery.js own content), grunt will run ok.

Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

        // Project configuration.
        grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            import: {
                options: {},
                default: {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'static/js/default/',
                    src: '**/*.js',
                    dest: 'static/js/stage/default/',
                    ext: '.js',
                }
            }
        });

        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-import');
        grunt.registerTask('default', ['import']);

};
```

I've read the docs of the plugins I use, but I found no option that may help. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead import all your files in the main.js

why you don't let grunt do this?

you can use concat and uglify for this:

see: [Grunt concat all package.json dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915222/grunt-concat-all-package-json-dependencies/36917381#36917381)

have you tried just use that cwd:

```
'static/**/*.js',
```

also can you share your gruntfile.js? so I can have a better look.

I hope that helped you.